# Phonegap:Login Through LinkedIn Error While Getting Access Token

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm trying to implement Login through LinkedIn using the following link [Login through LinkedIn](https://gist.github.com/efc88a38da25ff4e9283)
.

Below is my code`

```
            var oauth_info = {};
            var consumer_key = "";
           var shared_secret = "";
            var oauth = OAuthSimple(consumer_key, shared_secret);

            function parse_response(response) {
                response.replace(new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"), function($0, $1, $2, $3) { oauth_info[$1] = $3; });
                console.log("oauth_token1="+oauth_info.oauth_token);
            }

            function linkedInLogin()
            {

                var url = oauth.sign({action: "GET", path: "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken", parameters: {oauth_callback: "http://www.example.com/"}}).signed_url;
                console.log("url==="+url);
                $.ajax(
                       {
                       url:url,
                       data: {},
                       success: function(data){
                       console.log("inside success");
                       console.log("response==="+data);
                       parse_response(data);
                      console.log("oauth_token2="+oauth_info.oauth_token);
                       var params = data;
                        params = params.split('&');
                       for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                       var y = params[i].split('=');
                       if(y[0] === 'oauth_token') {
                       localStorage.oauth_token = y[1];
                       console.log("oauth_token=="+localStorage.oauth_token);
                       }
                       if(y[0]==='oauth_token_secret')
                       {
                       localStorage.oauth_token_secret=y[1];
                       console.log("oauth_token_secret=="+localStorage.oauth_token_secret);
                       }
                       }

                       step2();
                       },
                       error: function(error) {
                       console.log("error");
                       client_browser.close();
                       },
                       dataType: 'text',
                       type: 'GET'
                       });                    
            }
            function step2()
           {

                var authoriseurl='https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token='+oauth_info.oauth_token+'';                    
                window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(authoriseurl);
                window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function(loc){
                    console.log("on loc changed");
                    linkedInChanged(loc);
                };

            }

            function linkedInChanged(loc)
            {
                console.log("inside loc changed");
               if (loc.indexOf("http://www.example.com/") > -1) { 
                  window.plugins.childBrowser.close(); 
                    console.log("oauth_token3="+oauth_info.oauth_token);
                   var index, verifier = '';            
                   var params = loc.substr(loc.indexOf('?') + 1);
                   params = params.split('&');
                   for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                      var y = params[i].split('=');
                       if(y[0] === 'oauth_verifier') {
                           verifier = y[1];
                           console.log("verifier===="+verifier);
                       }

                   }
                   var acces_url= access_token_url(verifier);
                   oauth.reset();
                   console.log("oauth_token4="+oauth_info.oauth_token);
                   //console.log("oauth_info"+oauth_info[0][0]+"===="+oauth_info[0][1]);
                   //var url = oauth.sign({action: "GET", path: "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken", parameters: {oauth_verifier: verifier}, signatures: oauth_info}).signed_url; 
                   console.log("access _url="+acces_url);

                   $.ajax(
                          {
                          url:acces_url,
                          data: {},
                          success: function(data){
                          console.log("inside access token success");
                         console.log("response==="+data);
                          var params = data;
                          params = params.split('&');
                          for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                          var y = params[i].split('=');
                          if(y[0] === 'oauth_token') {
                          localStorage.linkedIn_access_Token = y[1];
                          console.log("linkedIn_access_Token=="+localStorage.linkedIn_access_Token);
                          }
                          if(y[0]==='oauth_token_secret')
                          {
                          localStorage.linkedIn_access_secret=y[1];
                          console.log("linkedIn_access_secret=="+localStorage.linkedIn_access_secret);
                          }
                          }
                          },
                         error: function(error){
                          console.log("error=="+error.responseText);
                          },
                          dataType: 'text',
                          type: 'GET'
                          });   



               }
            }


            function get_url_vars_from_string(url) {
                var vars = [], hash;
                var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
                {
                    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                    vars.push(hash[0]);
                    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                }
                return vars;

            }

            function access_token_url(pin) {
                oauth.reset();  
                //alert(oauth_info.oauth_token);
                var url = oauth.sign({action: "GET", path: "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken", parameters: {oauth_verifier: pin}, signatures: oauth_info}).signed_url;
               // alert("url="+url);

               return url;
            }
```

`
On click of a button the linkedInLogin method is called.
I'm not able to get the access token from this code.The ajax call for access token results in Error oauth_problem=token_rejected

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found out where the issue comes from.

So, I've come to the request for the accessToken, and have to generate the signature. When I call OAuth.completeRequest() - this is where the signature gets generated - I pass two parameters, and the second one is an object that contains four things (the first two are application settings and next two are from my first request, for the request token):

1. The api key.
2. The api secret.
3. The request token.
4. The request token secret.

The fourth one was missing on my end. That was the problem.

Also - I'm using this OAuth library - http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/oauth.js, so the methods/functions on your end could have completely different name. But you've got the idea.

Hope this helps ;)